# Compile libxml2 on OSX 10.9.5 xcode 6 with error WITH_PYTHON does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL

Tags: libxml2

Trying to compile compile libxml2 from source on OSX 10.9.5 xcode 6 with tools installed and i keep getting this error:

I have tried installing libxml2 with brew but couldn't get development version.

```
$ ./autogen.sh
I am going to run ./configure with no arguments - if you wish 
to pass any to it, please specify them on the ./autogen.sh command line.
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: You should add the contents of the following files to 'aclocal.m4':
libtoolize:   '/opt/lo/share/aclocal/libtool.m4'
libtoolize:   '/opt/lo/share/aclocal/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize:   '/opt/lo/share/aclocal/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize:   '/opt/lo/share/aclocal/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize:   '/opt/lo/share/aclocal/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: Consider adding 'AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])' to configure.in,
libtoolize: and rerunning libtoolize and aclocal.
libtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
acinclude.m4:4: warning: underquoted definition of AC_TRY_EVAL2
acinclude.m4:4:   run info Automake 'Extending aclocal'
acinclude.m4:4:   or see http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Extending-aclocal
configure.in:38: error: automatic de-ANSI-fication support has been removed
/opt/lo/share/aclocal-1.13/obsolete.m4:26: AM_C_PROTOTYPES is expanded from...
configure.in:38: the top level
autom4te: /opt/local/bin/gm4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
configure.in: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
configure.in: You should verify that configure.in invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE,
configure.in: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory,
configure.in: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal)
Makefile.am:23: error: WITH_TRIO_SOURCES does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
Makefile.am:8: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
Makefile.am:18: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
Makefile.am:18:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
Makefile.am:18:   to 'configure.in' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
Makefile.am:18:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.in', make sure
Makefile.am:18:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
/opt/lo/share/automake-1.13/am/depend2.am: error: am__fastdepCC does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/opt/lo/share/automake-1.13/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'am__fastdepCC' is to add 'AC_PROG_CC'
/opt/lo/share/automake-1.13/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.in' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
/opt/lo/share/automake-1.13/am/depend2.am: error: AMDEP does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/opt/lo/share/automake-1.13/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'AMDEP' is to add one of the compiler tests
/opt/lo/share/automake-1.13/am/depend2.am:     AC_PROG_CC, AC_PROG_CXX, AC_PROG_OBJC, AC_PROG_OBJCXX,
/opt/lo/share/automake-1.13/am/depend2.am:     AM_PROG_AS, AM_PROG_GCJ, AM_PROG_UPC
/opt/lo/share/automake-1.13/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.in' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
example/Makefile.am:5: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
python/Makefile.am:28: error: WITH_PYTHON does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
python/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
python/Makefile.am:34: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
python/Makefile.am:34:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
python/Makefile.am:34:   to 'configure.in' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
python/Makefile.am:34:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.in', make sure
python/Makefile.am:34:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
python/tests/Makefile.am:41: error: WITH_PYTHON does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
./autogen.sh: line 61: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me please.

Comment: There's no need to run `autogen.sh` unless you want to install *libxml2* from a Git checkout. If this is the case, try the latest version of the master branch. Otherwise, simply run `./configure`.

Comment: I have tried doing that and it seems to install fine but pkg_check_modules does not detect the library file. Is there anything i'm not doing right because I'm hoping compiling libxml2 from source could provide me with its development package.

Comment: Yes, installing *libxml2* from source will install all required development files. The *pkgconfig* file will be installed in `$prefix/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc` (note that the module name is `libxml-2.0`). If you use a non-standard installation prefix, you'll have to setup `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to find it.